# SQL Transpose or Pivot data with multiple values

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have a table with multiple columns and values.

Here is my SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
            LOB+' '+case when Que is null then 'NULL ' else Que End Que     
            , Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)LL_Outlier
            , Q1
            , Q_Median
            , Q3
            , Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)UL_Outlier
FROM    ##Brands_Que_Quartile
```

I get a list of Queue Names and my values but I need to switch so the Que is the Row Header and the LL_outlier, Q1, Q_Median, Q3, UL_Outlier as the Column List.

Original Data:

| Que | LowLimit | Q1 | Median | Q3 | Upperlim |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QueName1 | -11 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 21 |
| QueName2 | -16.5 | 0 | 1 | 11 | 27.5 |
| QueName3 | -14 | 1 | 6 | 11 | 26 |
| QueName... |  |  |  |  |  |

I can get the outputs using a cross apply and inner join but the que change and there is to many to do with where condition to set up the queue name.  Any suggestions???

Final Format would be:

| Quartile | Que Name1 | Que Name2 | Que Name3 | Que Name... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LowLimit | -11 | -16.5 | -14 |  |
| Q1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |
| Median | 3 | 1 | 6 |  |
| Q3 | 9 | 11 | 11 |  |
| Upperlim | 21 | 27.5 | 26 |  |

Comment: can you share samples from your input `##Brands_Que_Quartile` table, related to the output you already provided?

Comment: @Lemon updated with original data as what comes out of the query to the final format that it need it to look like.

Comment: Where is this output going? If this is going on an SSRS report you can easily use a MATRIX to get what you're after. If it has to be consumed by another SQL process, you might need a Dynamic SQL pivot, which requires loosening some default security configurations. If it's used in code (i.e. a C# program) you can format your PIVOT before passing the query. There are a bunch of solutions, none great that I know of, that vary in comparative quality depending on what your output is feeding into.